# Token based authentication in repository pattern project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have created a project based on repository pattern. And used this tutorial to implement token based authentication [Tutorial Link here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/).

Here's my code:

**ValuesController.cs**

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAuth(string Username, string Password)
    {
        return Ok(_au.Authenticate(Username, Password)); //returns true or false
    }
```

**IAuthenticator.cs**

```
namespace AuthSO.Core.Interface
{
    public interface IAuthenticator:IDisposable
    {
        bool Authenticate(string Username, string Password);
    }
}
```

**Authenticator.cs**

```
namespace AuthSO.Core.Manager
{
    public class Authenticator : IAuthenticator, IDisposable
    {
        public IGetData _get;
        public Authenticator(IGetData _get)
        {
            this._get = _get;
        }
        public bool Authenticate(string Username, string Password)
        {
            return _get.Authenticate(Username, Password);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            //left empty here, nothing to dispose here i guess
        }
    }
}
```

AuthenticatorProvider.cs

```
namespace AuthSO.API.Provider
{
    public class AuthenticatorProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            using (IAuthenticator _auth = new Authenticator()) //I'm getting an error here
            {
                bool result = _auth.Authenticate(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (!result)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);

        }
    }
}
```

Issue :

[image]

How can i solve this issue. I'm using Autofac for dependency injection.

[My sample project with this issue is in my github repo](https://github.com/darthranjith/TokenAuthIssue)

Any advice would be helpful, Thank you.

**Update #1:**

I tried using IDisposable still gets me this error, please see the updated Authenticator.cs code. (TokenAuthIssue/AuthSO.Core/Manager/Authenticator.cs in github)

[image]

Update #2:

I tried using this

```
using (IAuthenticator _auth = new Authenticator(new GetData()))
```

but again i got error

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ValuesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'AuthSO.API.Controllers.ValuesController' does not have a default constructor
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

This is clearly a dependency injection issue. Please guide me to the solution.

Comment: Are you sure IAuthenticator implements IDisposable? Could you post the IAuthenticator class?

Comment: The error is rather clear, and unrelated to repository patterns or authentication. You tried to use a class that *doesn't* implement the IDisposable interface. The `using(...)` statement is syntactic sugar for calling `IDisposable.Dispose()`.

Comment: Please see my updated question, i have added IAuthenticator.cs and also the IDisposable.

Comment: Did you read the error message you got?  **"Type 'AuthSO.API.Controllers.ValuesController' does not have a default constructor"**  That has *nothing* to do with the `IDisposable` or the `IAuthenticator`.

Comment: Please take a look at this link [ValuesController](https://github.com/darthranjith/TokenAuthIssue/blob/master/AuthSO.API/Controllers/ValuesController.cs). I have injected a dependency, having an empty constructor didn't worked either.

Comment: Ok, the issue is nothing to do with IDisposable or the IAuthenticator. So what went wrong and what i need to do. Please tell me this atleast.

Comment: Paste your values controller into the question and remove all of the irrelevant code.

Comment: @RanjithVaradan you should only ask one question per post (or some related questions), now your creating a thread on how to fix all of your problems. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Looks like IAuthenticator has not inherited from IDisposable.
When your using 'using' IDisposable makes sure it can dispose the variable from the using statement after the using scope has ended.